# Use json to generate output eventemitter

Tags: angular

The title almost said what I want to express.I wonder is there any way to generate output eventemitter by json in Angular. so i can get the certain
type of event and i can do other operations outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass one value out of an event emitter. But there is nothing stopping this value being an object.

```
@Output() event = new EventEmitter<any>();

emitEvent($event) {
    this.event.emit({type: 'key', value: $event})
}
```

Comment: I know i can output object with eventemitter,i was wondering if there is any way to add new properties on the generated instance.But thanks anyway